# Arabic Prawn Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, prawn

Since the Arabic letters appeared as unknown characters while using prawn gem alone ,  I installed the Arabic-Prawn gem 0.0.1 to print data in arabic .
I used as a test the below code

```
Prawn::Document.generate('hello.pdf') do  
  font "#{Prawn::BASEDIR}/data/fonts/artro.ttf"   
  font_size 16
  self.text_direction = :rtl
  long_text = "مرحبا يا العالم"
  text long_text.fix_arabic_glyphs  
end
```

First it displays the below error:

```
undefined method `fix_arabic_glyphs'
```

so I included the prawn in the class , the error disappeared but the Arabic letters are still not shown (represnted as _).
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and this solved it for me:

https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/issues/921

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by using another font only.
Some characters are not defined for some fonts . 
So using a font that defines all characters for arabic language is the best solution

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem